# C# SOAP Client using WebForm and listing results

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, webforms

I'm very new to SOAP and C# but I trying to learn by building a simple SOAP web client. I've create a web form with a single button and listbox. Clicking the button sends a SOAP call to the web services, returns a simple result and displays in the list box. That method (getCountRegisteredSubscribers) doesn't require input and returns an int. Next I want to return information about subscribers using another method called getSubscriber. This method does require input (subscriber name) and will return several results. I'm struggling with how to make the call by passing the subscriber name and listing the results in my listbox, would really appreciate any suggestions!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebApplication2.WebReference.SMFAdmin ws = new WebApplication2.WebReference.SMFAdmin();

            ListBox1.Items.Add("Request Submitted");
            ListBox1.Items.Add(""+ ws.getCountRegisteredSubscribers());
            //ListBox1.Items.Add("" + ws.getSubscribers("subname"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I've added a variable to store the subscriber name, however, it's returning 'WebApplicaiton2.WebReference.Subscriber' in my listbox. Any ideas how to fix this? There are several items associated with each subscriber, how do I get them to list inside my listbox? Thanks in advance.

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var subName = "subscriber 1";

        WebApplication2.WebReference.SMFAdmin ws = new WebApplication2.WebReference.SMFAdmin();

        ListBox1.Items.Add("Request Submitted");
        ListBox1.Items.Add(""+ ws.getCountRegisteredSubscribers());
        ListBox1.Items.Add("" + ws.getSubscriber(subName));

    }


}
}
```

Comment: You'll need to take the results from the web service call (presumably a `List<T>` or an array) and loop through them, adding the items one at a time to the `ListBox`.  It's better to make the call to the web service on it's own (instead of in `Items.Add`) so in case of an error you can do something with it.   You might also look to see if `Items` has an `AddRange` method, which may eliminate the need for a loop, depending (again) on how the data is being returned.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, can you provide a code example? very new to this and not having any luck getting there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Exception message, its seems getSubscribers doesn't take String value as parameter. So what you have to do this something like this.

```
ws.getSubscribers(new SubscriberNameInfo 
{
  *** value goes here **
});
```

I don't know the Detail of `SubscriberNameInfo` class, so I can't specified the properties.

**Note:** The second comment from the above answer is similar, I just added some code snippets.

I hope, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through the result and insert them to list box.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebApplication2.WebReference.SMFAdmin ws = new WebApplication2.WebReference.SMFAdmin();

    ListBox1.Items.Add("Request Submitted");
    ListBox1.Items.Add("" + ws.getCountRegisteredSubscribers());
    ListBox1.Items.Add("" + ws.getSubscribers("subname"));

    List<string> lstOutput = new List<string>();
    lstOutput = ws.getSubscribers("subname");
    lstOutput.ForEach(eachItem => ListBox1.Items.Add(eachItem));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however, there's a problem with using the getSubscribers method:

Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'WebApplication2.WebReference.SMFAdmin.getSubscribers(WebApplication2.WebReference.SubscriberNameInfo)' has some invalid arguments 28 25 WebApplication2
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'WebApplication2.WebReference.SubscriberNameInfo' 28 43 WebApplication2

Comment: You can create an instance of SubscriberNameInfo and set the property accordingly before passing in to the function getSubscribers.  The SubscriberNameInfo probably has some similar to name (maybe) as a property where you may set it.